# Delete or clear ALL data objects in UITableView with alert button?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, nsarray, nsobject

OK, I really have searched through the topics that seem to cover this but still have not found one that works for me. This list is made by sending every UIWebView page load here. At some point if the user would like to clear this list I have a button that brings up an alert view that just confirms that they want to clear and then press OK to clear. Please, tell me how I can do this. About halfway down you can find my clearAllData which is clearAllRecents alert button but my void function underneath that is my ?

```
#import "RecentViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface RecentViewController ()

@end

@implementation RecentViewController

@synthesize recent, explorerView;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    recent = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"Recent"] mutableCopy];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (IBAction)cancelButtonTapped
{
    [self setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
    [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:true];
}

- (IBAction)clearAllRecents
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                      initWithTitle:@"clear all recents?"
                      message:@"press ok to clear"
                      delegate: self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel"
                      otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
    [alert show];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        //clear all recent objects??????????????????????????????????????????????
    }
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [recent count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [recent objectAtIndex:(recent.count - indexPath.row - 1)];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:20.0];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    explorerView.urlField.text = [recent objectAtIndex:(recent.count - indexPath.row - 1)];
    [explorerView textFieldShouldReturn:explorerView.urlField];
    [self.presentingViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:true];
    explorerView = nil;
    recent = nil;
    tableView = nil;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [recent removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:recent forKey:@"Recent"];
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex      {

if (buttonIndex == 1) {
    [recent removeAllObjects];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:recent forKey:@"Recent"];
    [yourTableView reloadData];
}}
```

That should do it.

Comment: I tried this and the problem I get is [yourTableView reloadData]; yourTableView of coarse is not right for me. I tried UITableView and reloadData is not known. Just tableView throws up errors and suggests I use UITableView.

Comment: I failed to mention this was a uitableview in a UIViewController. So, I fixed the unknown method by adding @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView; to my .h and connecting it in IB. So, now the table clears but as soon as I return to the tableview it's populated again with all the data. What am I missing?

Comment: Your problem is `- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    recent = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:@"Recent"] mutableCopy];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}`
Every time the view loads, `recent` is being assigned the values from your user defaults.  If you want to clear the values permanently, you will need to reset the `arrayForKey:@"Recent"`.  Otherwise, you will need to find another way to load the values-- perhaps by giving the user an option to reload recents. (See edited answer)